# How to resolve call to undefined curl_init()?

Tags: php, laravel, curl

There is a fatal error when I use `curl` from Laravel but a `curl` that exists in another file is working.

Why do these errors occur?

> fatal error: call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\curl_init()

##### `App\Http\Controller\FcmController`:

```php
class FcmController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send');
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        dd($result);

        curl_close($ch);
```

##### `App\Http\Controller\CurlContoller` (It works):

```
class CurlController extends Controller
{
    public static function getCurl($url, $params)
    {
        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url . $params);        
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);;
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type:application/json; charset=utf-8"));

        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch); 

        return json_encode($response);
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does it work if you prefix the function to a top level namespace `\curl_init`. For the statically called function inside `CurlController` it won't be needed.

Also, not specifically answering your question but if you are running Laravel 7 and above you could actually use the built in [http-client](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/http-client) implementation from Laravel. It is more expressive than curl.

Comment: he already said it's working fine in the other controller file.

Comment: @OMiShah I saw I misread his question and amended my answer. Thanks.